# Creating notification based on table insert in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, notifications

I am new to Android and my requirement is this. I am in need to develop an application that will list all the events (past and upcoming). These event details , I will fetch from tables and that table will have only past events. For the upcoming events, I will be inserting into the table which will create a notification for the same.

My doubts:

1. What is the table I should use (**SQLite**(*inbuilt*) or **MySql** from any hosting services) ?
2. If **SQLite**, Is there a way from GUI, I can insert data so that it will reach all users having this application?

To be simple, how I can achieve this entire functionality?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the table I should use (SQLite(inbuilt) or MySql from any hosting services) ?

If you want all user devices to access the same database, you will have to setup a MySQL server. As soon as the database is updated in your host, the changes will be reflected in the users apps - as soon as they reload the view or a new request is made. You can query your database every N seconds to keep things updated.

Comment: Thanks R.Costa. Is there a link to refer connecting to MySQL and what is the best MySQL hosting service ? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Regarding the server side, I would install something like XAMPP to try MySQL and test the system. You can worry about hosting providers later . To combine Android and MySQL, there are thousands of tutorials online; just use Google or Youtube to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will be my choice or MariaDB, MySQL's community fork.
You can start with this tutorial:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html